# R言語がこれからPythonに取って代わられてしまうのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3, r

R言語でできることが、Pythonでも出来るという話を聴いて、実際はそんなことあるのだろうかと疑問に感じています。R言語はpythonに取って代わられてしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: 汎用的なプログラミング言語は大体どれもチューリング完全なので、その意味でどの言語でもできることは一緒だと言えます。

Comment: ご質問の内容は「理論的に可能かどうか」ではなく、「プログラミング言語の流行り廃りがどうなっていくか？」という、未来予測となっています。スタック・オーバーフローではこのような、主観的にしか答えられそうにない質問は好まれていません。もう少し内容を細かくして、「Rの〇〇という機能はPythonでも生産性良く書けるか？」「R言語やPythonを使っている人数の統計はあるか？」などの、何かしら指標をもって答えられるご質問にして頂けると、答えることができるかもしれません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107038